# URL link does not function when resizing a tabular object to textwidth

Tags: tables, hyperref, urls, width, resize

When I want to resize a table to textwidth, links to web pages and references are not functioning anymore (the hyperlink boxes are moved to another place) whereas I don't encounter this problem when I don't resize a table to textwidth.

However, I need to do this and both `resizebox` (1st example) and `adjustbox` (2nd example) give problems.

How can I solve this? Thank you! (I work in TeXstudio and use LuaLaTeX for compilation)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%%% change size by resizebox
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption for the table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}   \\ \midrule
        Problems & Help & \href{stackoverflow.com}    {stackstacksstackstackstacktacstackstackstackstackstackstackstack} \\
        & Search & \href{google.com}{Your friend}     \\
   \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }   
\end{table}

%%% change size by adjustbox
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption for the table.}
    \label{tab:table2}
     \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}   \\ \midrule
        Problems & Help & \href{stackoverflow.com}    {stackstacksstackstackstacktacstackstackstackstackstackstackstack} \\
        & Search & \href{google.com}{Your friend}     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
     \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your links are wrong it should be `\href{http://stackoverflow.com}` but beside this it works fine for me. I tried with texlive 2016 and 2017 (pretest). You should be aware that it is not good practice to resize a tabular like this, you will get uneven font sizes.